# How login into AAD with ADAL and MFA

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am trying to create a nodejs api, that connects to to Azure Active directory using the ADAL plugin (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs).

All works ok for normal users, but if a user has MFA (Multi-Factor Authentification) enabled, it fails and throws and error message.
I found this related to ADAL-MFA: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/issues/151 but it's not clear for me from his answer if it's possible or not, and how to implement MFA.

The plugin has very poor documentation and it's not clear for me how I can retrieve the error message and vars from it. It's says that the error var is a object but it's a string.

Here is my code from the endpoint which works for normal users:

```
      var adal = require('adal-node');
      var AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;
      var authorityUrl = parameters.authorityHostUrl + '/' + parameters.tenant;
      var resource = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';
      var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, true, new adal.MemoryCache);

context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(resource, parameters.username, parameters.password, parameters.clientId, function(err, token) {

    if(err){

      mysql_connection.end();
      return callback(null, {
          status: false,
          error: err.stack,
          log: logging.message,
          test: 1
      });
    }
)};
```

So basically I need to use user credentials (e-mail and password) to connect to AAD api, but server to server (my nodeJS api to AAD api). And it needs to work with MFA.

`(web app -> nodeJS API -> AAD API)`

`acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword` worked perfectly for this, but it does not work with MFA, or I don't know to make the correct adjustments to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow (ROPC), and hit one of the exact scenarios why I tell people not to use it. (except maybe for test automation)

You can't use ROPC with users that have MFA. Neither can you use it with users who are federated from on-prem AD or Microsoft personal accounts. Or with users whose password has expired and needs to be reset.

You need to switch your API to acquire the token using either On-behalf-of grant flow (exchanges the access token your API got for a new token, continuing the delegation) or client credentials flow (acquire token with app credentials alone, no user context).

[On-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)

Comment: OK, but I'm trying to use one of their the libraries they mentioned in their documentation ADAL for nodeJS, however this library only has 3 connection functions: acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword, acquireTokenWithClientCredentials, acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode. I looked at the functions in the code, and only the first one supports connection with USER credentials.

Comment: In that case the support for on behalf of is missing from the library which kinda sucks. You might need to do it manually with http requests for now, unless using client credentials is an option.

Comment: That indeed sucks a bit, but with a bit of extra work I can do it also with http requests, however it's the second time I'm reading the documentation you sent, and it's not clear on it what I need to do when a client has MFA. I'm quoting: "The middle-tier service should surface this error to the client application so that the client application can provide the user interaction to satisfy the conditional access policy."

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that "On-behalf-of-flow" doesn't take any params for user name and password? I need to be able to login with user credentials.

Comment: @Spreadzz I think you have a few options, want to have a short call to chat through your goals and options? My email is on my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Daniel is very knowledgeable, would recommend :) My main question for you is why do you want to handle the user's password? That's not the way OpenID Connect is designed to work. The user should login against their identity provider, and your API should get only a token which proves the user's identity. Maybe there is some kind of misunderstanding on how it all is supposed to work on the client side?

Comment: @junas, well the scenario in which I'm trying to use it is a bit more complicated

Comment: True, I'm not aware of the full picture here. Daniel might be able to look through your case with you :) Do write your own answer if you end up solving the issue with something different. Helps people who find this question in the future.

Comment: @junas, well the scenario in which I'm trying to use it is a bit more complicated. The user needs to login through our website, the credentials are sent first to our nodejs api, then the nodejs api needs to validate the credentials on AAD. acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword from ADAL is perfect for this, it just doesn't work with MFA. Daniel, yes I will send you a e-mail.

Comment: Yeah that's not really a scenario supported by the protocol as a whole. The "real" way to validate a user is to make them authenticate by sending them to Azure AD with a redirect/pop-up. Then if you get a valid ID token back, they logged in successfully :)

Comment: @Daniel, I sent you an e-mail with more details. I also update my question, and mentioned the work flow I need to get it working.

Comment: And yeah with `(web app -> nodeJS API -> AAD API)`, your web app would have to authenticate user with AAD, acquire access token for NodeJS API, call it with the token, and then the Node API can exchange that token for another token to the AAD API. Works with MFA etc.

Comment: Hmm, what would be the best flow from their documentation to implement for what I need. I don't know if it's be but I get dumber and dumber the more I read their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-browser-to-web-application I would prefer not to have the popup.

Comment: To sign in against Azure AD, you have to show the Azure AD login page. And you can't embed it in an iframe. The flow used depends on app type though, usually Authorization Code flow (for back-end clients) or Implicit flow (for front-end JS clients). Okay there is also Device Code flow which is a bit different.

Comment: I'll make sure to drop any conclusions or answers we reach offline for future reference :). As always @juunas has nailed it, but we'll walk through a the options and see what's the best approach going forward.

Comment: @DanielDobalian I sent you a e-mail. It might have reached your spam. my e-mail is lucian @ digitalgarage.ro